# Android, How can I apply CSS into WebView?

Tags: android, css, view

I want to use WebView, in order to show some paragraphs to user.
In XML, I have written following code:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width  = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
    android:background    = "#190306"
    android:textColor     = "#FFDEC2"
    android:autoLink      = "web" />
```

But background, text color and autolink do not recognize and emulator shows webview with white background and black text color.

How can I apply CSS into this webview?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying changes to the webview as an object. What you need to do is create a css file and use that in whatever pages your webview is pointing to.

Answer (score 11):

I have added following code in the activity and it works fine, now.

```
final WebView page = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
String text = "<html><head>"
          + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #ffdec2; background-color: #1F0C01;}"
          + "</style></head>"
          + "<body>"
          + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
          + getString(R.string.intro_content) 
          + "</p> "
          + "</body></html>";

page.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Using inline CSS would've been my second suggestion, and its good you've used it. Glad its working :)

Comment: can i override the css written inside the webpage that is being hit by the webview?