# Android webview.loadData & CSS

Tags: android, android-layout

I am loading html content from a SQLite database.  I am using a webview.loadData to load the content from a string once I get it from the database.

I have CSS in the html file and it is not loading when the page is displayed.  All the content is there, but no styling at all.  Here is my html that i am loading from the db.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .Heading { font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #000066; margin-top: 5px; } 
    .TextBody { font-size: 14px; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; } 
    .UL { }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="Heading">My Heading</div>
<div class="TextBody">My text.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why CSS does not work for me with an internal style sheet?  I don't think storing the CSS in the assets will work for me because i'm pulling the html from the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014519/android-how-can-i-apply-css-into-webview) helped me. In particular the "encoding" value of

```
loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Hope that helps. (Even if it is a little belated.)