# How to display HTML text with CSS classes in it in a TextView?

Tags: android, html, css, textview

Example:

```
.modal-body{}; 
.table{}; 
.class{}; 
<html>
<body><p class= ".modal-body">sample body</p></body>
</html>
```

I have the above sample text stored in a variable and I want to display it in a textview or webView. Can anyone suggest me the way of doing it? I couldn't find solution I require.

Answer (score 0):

You could [load html string in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816464/how-to-load-html-string-in-a-webview) On a `textView` as far as I know you can't since there are native properties used to style text so, there is no point.
If you use [.fromHtml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview) there are just a couple of tags available but no css.

Comment: I have used Webview. But, it is parsing the HTML tags but not the CSS styling.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6014762/15298643) . Also as the comment on that answer, using inline css may work too.